# Get records of not existing placeholders

Tags: php, mysql, dictionary

I want to query my database for the translation of some placeholders (dictionary-function).
For the error-handling, I wish to ouput the placeholder, which are not existing in the dictionary database.

Query Example:

```
SELECT `de` as `text` FROM `dictionary` WHERE `name` IN 
  ('button_search','eventlist_addons','eventlist_city',
   'eventlist_date','eventlist_name','gender_both',
   'gender_female','gender_male','startmenu_insert','startmenu_register') 
ORDER BY `name`
```

I can determine, if the count of records which are given back is not the same as I aspacted it. But now I want to know, which placeholder/s was/were not in the database and output it/them.

Can I do it with a query in MySQL or is there a cool way in PHP?

My function for it is this:

```
function dictionary($text)
{
    global $db,$lang;
    preg_match_all('/##D##(.*)##D##/mU',$text,$matches);
    $matches[0] = array_unique($matches[0]);
    $matches[1] = array_unique($matches[1]);
    sort($matches[0]);
    sort($matches[1]);
    $sql = "SELECT `".$lang."` as `text` FROM `dictionary` WHERE `name` IN ('".implode("','",$matches[1])."') ORDER BY `name`";
    $result = $db->query($sql);
    $num = $db->num($result);
    if($num > 0)
    {
        if($num == $matches[1])
        {
            while($trans = $db->assoc($result))
            {
                $replace[] = $trans['text'];
            }
        }
        else
            echo_msg("Missing Placeholder","Error",true);
        $text = str_replace($matches[0],$replace,$text);
    }
    return $text;
}
```

**Edit**
Long stroy short: I Want to get a result, wich contains all values, whicht are not a listet in the column 'name'

Comment: IN has a corresponding NOT IN

Comment: I don't want to get alle records, which are not in the list. I want to get alle items from the list, which are not in the table.